# I need to maximise a function that contains a CDF of a normal in matlab

Tags: matlab, cdf

I need to solve for the following in matlab:

```
gamma = max_{x} [1 - F(x)] * x
```

Where `x` is normally distributed with some mu and some sigma and `F(x)` is the CDF evaluated at x. How do I go around doing this? 
I have tried to write a separate script with the function, using `normcdf` within that, and then using `fminunc` with my function as an input argument, but that did not work. Any help would be much appreciated!
Edit:
So far I have a function:

```
function gamma = myfun(x,mu,sigma)
mu=0.0185;
sig=0.0216;
gamma = (-1)*(1-normcdf(x,mu,sig))*x;
end
```

And in the main file:

```
x0=0;
gamma = fminunc(@myfun,x0);
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? :)

Comment: function gamma = myfun(x,mu,sigma)
mu=0.0185;
sig=0.0216;
gamma = (1-normcdf(x,params(1,1),params(1,2)))*x;
end

Comment: And then within the main code:
x0=0;
gamma = fminunc(@myfun,x0);

Comment: Add this to your question. You can edit it.